# AFNetworking - AFHTTPRequestOperation - check failure for setUploadProgressBlock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I could send an image to a server, but I have a problem.
I can check failure with simple block like this :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);
}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
    }
 ];
[operation start];
```

But I can't see the progress of the sending with this block. So I found a special block with progress call back like this :

```
[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
}];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

The problem is that with setUploadProgressBlock there is not "failure: " ...

So my question is... There is a way to check if sending failed or no??

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be working fine, it will give progress and also go to failed block if something gone wrong:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] init];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
 NSLog(@"success: %@", operation.responseString);
 }
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 // If access token is null , we ask to the user if he wants to sign in or sign up ????
 NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
 }
 ];
 [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
 NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
 }];
[operation start];
```

Comment: It won't do the request twice right??? 
Because I had the feeling that setUploadProgressBlock launched directly the sending...

Comment: No it wont, you fire request only once with [operation start] method.

Comment: You should probably use `[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];` and not `[operation start];`

Answer (score 0):

You can set both blocks and achieve what you want.